# Doubts on the success of a project structure

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

[image: project structure]

I am having a doubt regarding a project structure.

I am having a project PROJ-1 that makes use of SWCs created by an another project PROJ-2 
The PROJ-2 make use of some classes (diagram:- A, B, C ) present at some  other location on my desktop ( I actually make use of those classes ( A,B,C) , as i generally need them in all projects) .

But now, i am facing a situation, where PROJ-1 too needs those classes. I fear if i make use of those classes again in PROJ-1, then it would mess up ( As the swcs coming from PROJ-2 are already using those classes (A,B,C) )

What should i do now ??

Thanks.
Vishwas.

Comment: Your explanation is too messed up us...

Comment: is it possible to use those classes from the swc?

Comment: amm.. actually not sure but accessing via swc doesnot seem professional way.. especially because those classes are "general" classes. ( I am creating project document, and doing this way would be noticeable to auditors as incorrect structure). I wanna know if someone has experience how to control repeating classes as i want above.

Comment: Of course you can use the same classes in different SWC files. Why would that be a problem?

Comment: May be you are right, but I actually had bad experience with this type of structure previously. I saw that there occurs a lot of strange behaviours in such structure and are hard to debug. So just in case, there were a better method. 
Btw, what about RSLs? Can RSLs be helpful here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fragment the "shared" classes to a separate swc lib altogether, that can be used by both proj1 and proj2.

It is a VERY bad idea to compile the same classes directly into proj1 that are already inside the swc generated from proj2. It won't give CTE's or RTE's since the FP will automatically use the class definitions that it encounters first but the big problem is in usage.
If anything changes in one of those classes, but you forget to re-compile one of both projects, you'll be running into very erratic behaviour. For instance proj2 compiles and runs perfectly on it's own, but the moment you run the binary of proj1 it will behave differently since it will use the definition of the class as it was compiled into proj1.

Comment: hmm..thanks,
Btw, what about RSLs? Can RSLs be helpful here ?

Comment: Advantages:
1/ RSLs get cached -> faster loading times
2/ reduced compilation times
3/ reduced file sizes
Disadvantages:
1/ cross-domain issues
2/ harder debugging
3/ more complicated workflow since the RSL needs to be online before usage

So it's really a matter of taste and outweighing benefits to disadvantages